# Sorting one element in a sorted container

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a vector of sorted objects. At some point one of the objects gets updated and that element (only) has to be sorted again.

What is the best approach? std::sort() on the whole container (if the container is already sorted, is it faster?) or erase() the object and insert() it where it should be?

EDIT: in this case I have to use a vector container

Comment: why not shift the rest once found its position?

Answer (score 5):

In theory, you should use a combination of `std::lower_bound` and `std::insert`, as shown in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void insert(T value, std::vector<T>& data) {
  auto it = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), value);
  data.insert(it, value);
}

template<typename C>
void show(const C& data) {
  for(const auto & item : data) {
    std::cout << item << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {

  std::vector<int> data { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9 };
  show(data);
  insert(3, data);
  show(data);
  insert(6, data);
  show(data);
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ example.cpp -std=c++14
./a.out
1 2 4 5 7 9
1 2 3 4 5 7 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
```

`std::lower_bound(beg, end, val)` will find the iterator pointing to the first element in the range `[beg, end)` that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value (cf. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)); it only works for sorted containers. Its complexity is logarithmic in `std::distance(beg, end)`.

`std::vector<T>::insert(it, value)` will insert `value` before `it`.

In practice (for a relatively small number of elements), you may be better off using linear search up to the point of insertion and then `std::insert`. In other words: linear search is `O(N)`, and `std::lower_bound` is `O(log N)`, but linear search is faster (due to cache effects) for vectors with about 10-50 elements (your mileage may vary).

Answer (score 3):

- `std::sort` has a complexity of `O(n log n)`.
- removal and insertion has a complexity of `O(n)`.
- rotation has a complexity of `O(log n) + O(length_of_rotation)`.

You can use `std::lower_bound` to find the new place and `std::rotate` to fix order:

```
void update(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>::iterator old_it, int new_value)
{
    if (old_it == v.end()) {
        return;   
    }
    auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), new_value);
    *old_it = new_value;

    if (old_it < it) {
        std::rotate(old_it, old_it + 1, it);
    } else if (it < old_it) {
        std::rotate(it, old_it, old_it + 1);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/670dc821b02b5a26)

The advantage of `std::rotate` vs `remove`/`insertion` is the number of copy/move:
if you have to swap only the 2 first elements, `std::rotate` does only the swap, whereas remove shift all elements, and insert shift again the element in the other side.

Answer (score 1):

If the vector is already sorted, you can easily find the new place of the updated value by dichotomy (compare with value at size+2 and iterate ...). Then you shift all elements between old and new place.

This is a rather optimised way since the shift between old and new place is a condensed operation combining a `std::erase` and `std::insert`, but it will be more tedious to write and test...

Comment: exactly, using the same loop btw